# WebView Changes the Url Automatically

Tags: android, eclipse, url, webview

I am very new in App Development with Eclipse for android. I am able to make the buttons and links but am stuck at few places, and need help here.

The App has 3 button and a webview .

I am loading my Gmail account in webview by clicking the button . these buttonos are shortcuts like Inbox and Junk Box.So i should be able to check the mail by just clicking the inbox button.

The problems I face are:

1. When i click the inbox button for first time its ask for username and password but when i click login- It changes the webview Url to something else and ends with not found!! or error .I want to stop the Url from changing.
2. Webview Opens a new default webbrowser of my phone with the address bar on the top.
   I want to hide that address bar and dont want to use the default browser to open the Page.
   It has to be a smoth transaction without jumoing to URl page.

Hi Thank you for the response but i have few errors here,1) Since i am using three button , to activate the webview i have used the switch view ,therefore i am not able to define  the above below is the sample code:

```
cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {


private Activity result;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

            public void onClick(View v)   
{
                { switch (v.getId()) 
{
                case R.id.can_button3:  
                Intent myintent1 = new Intent


(Launcher.this,cancelbutton.class); Toast.makeText(Launcher.this, "Cancellation ",

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true); 

    WebView.loadUrl("https://gmail.com/inbox");break;
} 
} } 
}
);

 junkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() //Next Button{private Activity 



result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomWebViewClient for your WebView. Override the following two functions:
`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` - To display the page within WebView
`onReceivedSslError` - To ignore SSL errors.

The code would look like this:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }

}
```

Add this WebViewClient to your WebView:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) result.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response but i have few errors here,

Comment: @user3357268 Please post the error log in your answer.

Comment: please don't implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading this way. If you do content like this will break your app: http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet